# AS3 - How to get current scene name in class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm playing around with flash, and I've created multiple scenes for things like menu's, buttons, etc. When trying to add event handlers for buttons that are in one scene, but not others, the compiler complains saying that it can't reference to objects that don't exist.

I figured the solution to be simple... Get the scene name, match that against an if statement and load the event handlers through the if statements...

However, after digging around on the net for far too long, I just can't seem to find a way to do this properly. Does anyone know a way?

I've tried using the following :

```
var scene:Scene = myflvandclassname.currentScene;
var sName:String = MovieClip.currentScene.name;

Both lead to an error "Access of possibly undefined property Scene through a reference with static type Class".
```

Comment: What did you try? Please include code, errors, etc

Comment: For the most part, I've been trying to assign the Scene name to a string variable. Errors were mostly "Access of possibly undefined property Scene through a reference with static type Class". Things I've tried = var sName:Scene = myflvandclassname.currentScene;, var sName:String = MovieClip.currentScene.name, and things of that sort.

Comment: Please edit it into the question, so it will be more accessible to others

Answer (score 0):

Omit MovieClip and scenes as source for organising your project, and code on the timeline. Use [Document class](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/concept_document_class.html) as entry point. This [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash--active-3233) should help you to grasp main concept.

```
package {

    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.display.StageAlign;
    import flash.display.StageScaleMode;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class StackOverflow extends Sprite {
        public function StackOverflow() {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);
        }

        private function onAdded(e:Event):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded);

            stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;
            stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;

            setup();
        }

        private function setup():void {
            const padding:int = 20;

            //Initiate your UI components and place them in the display list
            var menu:MyMenu = new MyMenu();
            var buttons:MyFooterButtons = new MyFooterButtons();
            var etc:AnotherComponent = new AnotherComponent();

            addChild(menu);
            addChild(buttons);
            addChild(etc);

            menu.x = menu.y = padding;
            //Place them and initialise with concrete information
        }
    }
}
```

For example, **MyMenu, MyFooterButtons, AnotherComponent** could be MovieClip/Sprite in the library with [export settings](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b8ea63-7fee.html), where you did all your work with placement, styling, etc

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem. I wanted to check from an external Class the current scene name and depending on the name (name of the game level) to pass some values in some attributes…  So what I did and it worked is that.

```
//main in 1st frame of the fla

stop();

var myCheckSceneClass: CheckSceneClass = new CheckSceneClass();
myCheckSceneClass.myCurrentScene = currentScene;
myCheckSceneClass.checkScene();

//CheckSceneClass


package {
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Scene;


    public class CheckSceneClass extends flash.display.MovieClip {

        public var myCurrentScene : Scene;



        public function CheckSceneClass () {


        }


        public function checkScene() {
            switch (myCurrentScene.name) {
                case "Scene 1":
trace("It is the 1st Scene");                   
break;
                default:
                    trace("Error with Scene Name");
                    break;

            }

        }








    }

}
```